# Error when trying to create and join a channel in hyperledger fabric blockchain services

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to setup my own network using HyperledgerFabric. I have completed all the required steps and started the nodes. It worked fine and got the below response.

[image: Result of my response]

Then tried to create and join a channel using the commands stated below and i got this error.

> 2019-02-28 13:43:07.440 UTC [main] InitCmd -> ERRO 001 Cannot run peer because cannot init crypto, folder "/app/HYPERLEDGER/fabric-samples/BaseNetwork/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/citizen.example.com/users/Admin@citizen.example.com/msp" does not exist

[image]

Comment: What is the docker version you are running?

Comment: Version:      18.03.1-ol

Comment: In that case, clear the volumes- docker volume prune, clear the containers, images. Re-pull. Also check if the volume paths in the yaml are correct.

Comment: Did the above suggestion worked??

Comment: sorry for late reply. It helps, Thanks

Comment: Do me a favor. I will post the same as answer to this question. Accept it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing docker version 18.03.1. If that doesn't helps try docker volume prune, clear the containers, images and re-pull.